# I am getting Request denied when I tried to get json response of places near to current location

Tags: android, json

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=gurudwar&radius=500&types=locality&sensor=true&key=0aSMA1WnWOIUNXILbCLs1wBScpm7EJfZAnQ8W6Q
```

I used this url to get the response but I am getting

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I tried changing API key also but still same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

TRY DIFFERENT API_KEY..may be api_key got expired https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=0ooCl3rakFqfnvWHu2EHzDSq6MaS7Bez28sz2Mw  I tried with different API_KEY but still the response is same

Comment: What is the procedure you did to get api_key..First you have to turn_on the **PlacesApi** in Services tab then you have to copy the api from **ApiAccess**

Comment: In my c:\ I created android folder and copied my debug.keystore("C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Android") .After that I followed the procedure from this link  http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: That api_key is for showing mapview inside an activity..To use JSon ypu have to use **placesApi**..[click here-link](https://code.google.com/apis/console) Go to this link and do what i said before in my previous comment